# Feature engineering, key error in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I am currently creating some additional features for my ML project.
I created one feature (f1), insert it as a new column and want to use it now to calculate another feature, but I get a KeyError.

```
df['f1'] = df['column1'] - df['column2'] -->works fine
```

f1 has dtype: timedelta64, e.g. '0 days', '43 days'.
Then I want to use this new column.

```
df['f2'] = df['f1'] + df ['column3'] --> Error occurs
```

Errors:

```
KeyError Traceback (Most recent call last)
KeyError 'f1'
```

I don't know, what I can change to make it work. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Could you include some sample data for your DF before creating `f1`?

Comment: Please create a [mre]

Comment: `f1` probably doesn't exist in your `df`

Comment: Data in f1 data dtype timedelta. sample df['f1'] = ['43 days', '0 days', '10 days']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the order you have written should works, if it gives error that f1 keys does not exist, maybe you are runing these lines in a notebook, and you are executing the second line before f1 created (like first line)

Comment: Im running it in Jupyter notebook and it is executed in the given order. Same error occurs when I try to change dtype. Like if it doesn't exists, as you say. But the column is the in df.